# how to assure that an event-emitter is to be sent to a component while it is initialized

Tags: angular, typescript

as shown below in the code, when `ngOnInit` of `floating-button-component` is called, i want to send `iDatePasser.dateOfSpray` to `env-risk.ts` .
by the time the following line of code is called

```
this._FromFloatingButtonToEnvironmentalRiskService.emitOnDataOfSpraySet(this.iDatePasser.dateOfSpray)
```

the component `env-risk.ts` is not initialized yet, resulting in any processing on `dataOfSpray` as follows for exampel:

```
this.iEnvRisk.dateOfSpray = this.dataOfSpray
let dateOfSpraySplitted = this.iEnvRisk.dateOfSpray.split("/")
```

to be `undefined`

what could be the solution to this situation please

**floating-button-component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.iDatePasser={} as IDatePasser
    this.iDatePasser.dateOfSpray = "";

    if (localStorage.getItem(environment.keyDateOfSpray) != undefined && localStorage.getItem(environment.keyDateOfSpray) != null) {
      this.iDatePasser.dateOfSpray = localStorage.getItem(environment.keyDateOfSpray) as string
      this.isActivateEnvRisk = true
      this._FromFloatingButtonToEnvironmentalRiskService.emitOnDataOfSpraySet(this.iDatePasser.dateOfSpray)
      console.log(this.debugTag, 'this.iDatePasser.dateOfSpray:',this.iDatePasser.dateOfSpray)
    }
}
```

**env-risk.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subEvtEmitter = this._FromFloatingButtonToEnvironmentalRiskService.getBroadcastEmitterOnDataOfSpray().subscribe((dataOfSpray:string) => {
      this.dataOfSpray = dataOfSpray
      console.log(this.debugTag, ' dataOfSpray:', this.dataOfSpray)
    })
    this.subscriptionCollector.push(this.subEvtEmitter)
}
```

Comment: If env-risk is not ready, do not display it. Use a spinner for example, waiting for the emission of DataOfSpray.

Comment: @GérômeGrignon do you mean that i can set a timie-out for two seconds and them emit that event??

Comment: not a set timeout, just don't display env-risk content until you have this dataOfSpray information. You can use a condition in your template with *ngIf